# How to enable proxy servers with anaconda python

Tags: python, proxy, firewall, anaconda

We are trying to get the conda install (on windows 8) to work behind a firewall via a proxy server.  Currently,  we are able to use pip to install packages while on our company network by using this at the command prompt:

```
pip install pandas --proxy=http://abc.def.xyz.com:1234
```

No passwords need to be specified,  just the proxy server and port. The [conda documentation](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/config.html?highlight=proxy) states that proxy servers are possible:

```
# Proxy settings: http://[username]:[password]@[server]:[port]
proxy_servers:
    http: http://user:pass@corp.com:8080
    https: https://user:pass@corp.com:8080
```

I have tried this with various combinations to see if I can get it to work with or without putting in my username and password.

```
# formats tried:
http: http://user:pass@abc.def.xyz.com:1234
http: http://abc.def.xyz.com:1234
```

I cannot seem to get it to work. Tried various combinations of quoting things too (passwords have special chars).  Also tried with and without the domain\user.

I can see under the hood, conda is using urlib3 (while pip may be using [urlib proxy handler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html)?).  Note that having your username and password in a file is generally frowned upon.

I know we could set up our own http or file location channel and put all the packages there and add the channel to the .condarc config settings. However I would prefer not to have to manage a repository of packages and versions locally.

So.... is there a way to specify,  in the .condarc file the proxy server and port (without user and password) so that conda install works behind a firewall just like pip install on the command line?  Or even an inline call like pip has and works... something like:

```
conda install pandas --proxy=abc.def.xyz.com:1234
```

Thanks in advance...

PS:  I really love conda.  I spent last weekend setting up many virtual environments on my home PC.  Documentation was great and everything worked flawlessly. Overall,  much better than pip... if only we could only get this to work inside our company :)

Comment: conda and pip are both using requests, which uses urllib3.

Answer (score 17):

Well,  this is embarrassing,  but good news.   I solved my problem with one more attempt at a change in the condarc file.

```
https: https://abc.def.xyz.com:1234
```

I guess pip worked ok with regular http,  while conda's addresses are all https sites:

```
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
```

I should have caught that!

Well,  I am now just happy that we have a solution to use conda behind our firewall, and without needing a user and password.  Awesome!

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so, where does the conda configuration file go?

Comment: Does anyone know where pip installed via anaconda 4.0.0 picks up the proxy from?

Comment: I could not find way to put proxy information in config. However, the environment variables http_proxy and https_proxy work just fine.

Comment: @dustin : just open your Anaconda prompt; the default path there (probably your directory under Users) should contain the .condarc file... now that you know where it is, just go find it and edit it with your preferred text editor.

Comment: @dustin : Are you on Windows? If so, where does the conda configuration file go?    One can get info on .condarc file path with conda command prompt :   conda info    and one can create .condarc file with command  :   conda config

Answer (score 14):

Late answer but maybe other people faced with this problem can benefit.

Create a .condarc file contaninig :

```
channels:
- defaults

# Show channel URLs when displaying what is going to be downloaded and
# in 'conda list'. The default is False.
show_channel_urls: True
allow_other_channels: True

proxy_servers:
    http: http://172.**.*.***:8080
    https: https://172.**.*.***:8080


ssl_verify: False
```

Change IP adresses with your own proxy settings.

Put this file in your user's main folder (for me : C:\Users\bakayim)

Restart your anaconda prompt

Comment: for me this worked:  ssl_verify: false
channels:
  - defaults
show_channel_urls: true
allow_other_channels: true
proxy_servers:
  http: http://proxy-master.mycompany.com:8080
  https: https://proxy-master.mycompany.com:8080

Answer (score 2):

Open Anaconda command and execute below command:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxyurl.com:8080

set HTTPS_PROXY=https://username:password@proxyurl.com:8443
```

Answer (score 0):

what wokred for me was the following `.condarc` file

```
channels:
  - r
  - defaults

proxy_servers:
  http: http://username:password@Proxyadresse:Proxyport
  https: https://username:password@Proxyadresse:Proxyport

ssl_verify: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I also set 2 Windows environment variables: (don't know if it was necessary)

```
Name: http_proxy
```

Variable: http://username:password@Proxyadresse:Proxyport

```
Name: https_proxy
```

Variable: https://username:password@Proxyadresse:Proxyport

Comment: It seems that anaconda ignores these settings, they have to go into `.condarc`

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that .condarc didn't have desired effect in my case (Windows 7). With `conda info` I could verify that it was loaded but it didn't have any effect.

I had to set forementioned environment variables in order to get connection from behind a proxy.

I was done as follows in command prompt:

```
set http_proxy=[protocol:your_proxy_address_here:port]
set https_proxy=[protocol:your_proxy_address_here:port]
```

Remove brackets. To verify (list) your concurrent settings just type: **set**

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Anaconda comes with .condar file in the user directory `C:\Users\User_name\.condarc`.

so all to do is just to edit the content as below:

```
channels:
  - defaults

show_channel_urls: True
allow_other_channels: True

proxy_servers:
    http: http://172.**.*.***:8080
    https: https://172.**.*.***:8080

ssl_verify: true
```

That's what worked for me.